# Spring boot 1.5.7 uploading file along with params using RestTemplate

Tags: spring-mvc, upload, resttemplate

I am getting myself familiar to Springboot. We are creating this Microservice based architecture were I am trying to consume this file upload service using RestTemplate.

Basically the Serve Side API code is

```
@PostMapping("/upload")

public ResponseEntity<?> fileUpload(@RequestParam String appender, 
                           @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
 ...
}
```

Now on the client side 
    @Override
    public String attachFile(String id, MultipartFile file) {
        String status = null;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

```
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> upParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, 
                                                 Object>();
    upParams.add("appender", id);
    upParams.add("file", file.getOriginalFilename());

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> request = 
            new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(upParams, headers);

    String response = restTemplate.postForObject(uploadEndPoint, request, 
                                                     String.class);
    return status;  
}
```

I get this error

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500
```

and if I change the line to below
     upParams.add("file", file);

I get Error

"Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile[\"inputStream\"]->java.io.FileInputStream[\"fd\"])

Comment: This Link will help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738896/file-upload-of-commonsmultipartfile-using-resttemplate-is-failing

Comment: This Link will help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738896/file-upload-of-commonsmultipartfile-using-resttemplate-is-failing