# File upload of CommonsMultipartFile using RestTemplate is failing

Tags: java, file, web-services, file-upload, multipartform-data

I'm trying to consume a web service that accepts a CommonsMultipartFile in the request. So, I created an HTTP client using Spring's RestTemplate. Below is the method that takes in URI and a MultipartFile as parameters. I'm trying to pass this file to the web service in the form of ByteArrayResource.

```
public String upload(String uri, MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    logger.info("URI: " + uri);

    ByteArrayResource fileAsResource = new ByteArrayResource(file.getBytes()) {
        @Override
        public String getFilename() {
            return file.getOriginalFilename();
        }
    };

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    parts.add("file", fileAsResource);
    parts.add("fileName", file.getOriginalFilename());

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(parts, httpHeaders);

    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = rest.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);

    this.setStatus(responseEntity.getStatusCode());
    return responseEntity.getBody();
}
```

This is how I'm creating a CommonsMultipartFile:

```
private MultipartFile getCommonsMultipartFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File file = new File("C:\\Dummy_Test.txt");

    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    FileItem fileItem = factory.createItem( "file", "multipart/form-data", false, "Dummy_Test.txt" );
    IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(file), fileItem.getOutputStream());
    MultipartFile commonsMultipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(fileItem);

    return commonsMultipartFile;
}
```

But whenever I run this client to hit the web service I keep getting this error.

```
 org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: resource loaded from byte array cannot be resolved to absolute file path; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: resource loaded from byte array cannot be resolved to absolute file path
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:453)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:377)
    at com.attikala.service.UploaderService.upload(UploaderService.java:118)
    at com.attikala.service.UploaderService.main(UploaderService.java:55)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: resource loaded from byte array cannot be resolved to absolute file path
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractResource.getFile(AbstractResource.java:107)
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractResource.contentLength(AbstractResource.java:116)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.getContentLength(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.write(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.write(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:1)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writePart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:288)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeParts(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:252)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeMultipart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:242)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:194)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:1)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:436)
    ... 4 more
```

Can someone help me in figuring out what's happening here?

Note: If I use the below code to upload the file, it works perfectly fine.

```
public String upload(String uri) {
    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

    FileSystemResource value = new FileSystemResource(new File("C:\\Dummy_Test.txt"));
    map.add("file", value);
    map.add("fileName", "Dummy_Test.txt");

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);

    return responseEntity.getBody();
}
```

So, I'm thinking, do I need to provide absolute path always for the file I'm uploading? I know I'm missing something here. Don't know what.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found what's happening.
Here I go -

when this statement

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = rest.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
```

gets executed, behind the scenes it's trying to extract the file of type `java.io.File` from the MultipartFile passed, and then get the file length. But MultipartFile is not of that type and as a result it was throwing an exception.

To fix that I had to also override `contentLength()` method when creating an instance of `ByteArrayResource`. Ta-da!

```
    ByteArrayResource fileAsResource = new ByteArrayResource(file.getBytes()) {

        @Override
        public String getFilename() {
            return file.getOriginalFilename();
        }

        @Override
        public long contentLength() throws IOException {
            return file.getSize();
        }
    };
```

Hope this helps if anyone runs into the same problem.

Comment: Worked for me.Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work. In my case I had to override the `getFile()`, see my solution below.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/my-app/user-tracking-script.js")
                .setCachePeriod(0)
                .resourceChain(false)
                .addResolver(new ResourceResolver() {
                    @Override
                    public Resource resolveResource(final HttpServletRequest request, final String requestPath, final List<? extends Resource> locations, final ResourceResolverChain chain) {
                        try {
                            final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                            headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));

                            final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

// RELEVANT PART BELOW
                            final ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(userTrackingScript, HttpMethod.GET, entity, byte[].class);
                            final ByteArrayResource fileAsResource = new ByteArrayResource(response.getBody()) {
                                @Override
                                public File getFile() throws IOException {
                                    final File tempFile = File.createTempFile("user-tracking", ".js");
                                    try (final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
                                        IOUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBody()), out);
                                    }
                                    return tempFile;
                                }
                            };
                            return fileAsResource;
                        } catch (final Exception e) {
                            log.error("Could not download user-tracking-script.js for URL: {}", userTrackingScript, e);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String resolveUrlPath(final String resourcePath, final List<? extends Resource> locations, final ResourceResolverChain chain) {
                        log.error("Unexpected call to resolveUrlPath by {}", resourcePath);
                        return null;
                    }
                })
        ;
```